# another way to express readiness for something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to express the idea that I am

> ready to begin

in a way that is personal and not excessively formal or stilted.

I have overused ready to begin something form. Other ways to do so can be "set to start", "ready for take the initial steps", "prepared to go", but none of these seems to work in the context.

All these following options are overly formal or informal or not as concise or emphatic.

> all set to begin
>
> set to go
>
> prepared to take the next step
>
> set to undertake this path
>
> all set to start

This is an statement with which a piece ends and therefore it needs a concise and emphatic quality which pretty captures the effect of "ready to begin" phrase with different words.

> ....John is capable of doing so much in this project. He will make a
>   difference in what this project ends up accomplishing. He is ready to
>   begin.

Any suggestions to convey this?

Comment: What is the context that they don't work in? Please note from the [expression-choice] [tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/expression-choice/info): "For a question to be tagged thus, **the alternatives to choose from must be explicitly provided** by the question asker. Please also provide as much detail as you can about the intended context or meaning." (my bold)

Comment: If *ready* all by itself doesn't serve, that is.

Comment: You're *set* (or *all set*), you're *fully prepped*, you're *waiting for the starting gun*, you're *rarin' to go*, you're *champing at the bit*, you're *as ready as you'll ever be*, you're *wondering what the hold-up is*....

Comment: upvoted suggestions. I have already tried all of these, but they are either too dramatic or formal which is not the effect I am going for. I added more details to OP to describe context. A good synonym of ready that is just as matter of fact and dynamic would help, but it's being hard to find it. The only reason i am not using "ready to begin," or ready as suggested above, which is perfect, is that i have overused it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm game for it!"

"I'm raring to go!"

"Let's do this!"

"I'm all set!"'

"Ready when you are!"

"I'm pumped!" (highly informal, and I'm lifting it from *Good Will Hunting*, if memory serves).

Comment: Yeah I tried these but they are either too informal or just not right for the context, which I explained more in the new details. "I am all set to start" is something I had thought about early on but it too is not as dynamic as "ready" in being the ending of the piece. upvoting for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your example, consider the idiom ***up to speed***, which basically means that the person already knows what needs to be known to do the job.

Comment: I can see that up to speed may work well in some cases; in this case it may be too informal. There is a comparable phrase "all set" that i considered and discarded as it too was informal for the use here.

Answer (score -1):

If you are requesting authorization to assign the task to Joe, (who is ready and waiting) you could say: "Joe is just waiting for your/the *say-so*.

Comment: Not requesting for authorization. Think of it as making a case for John in a recommendation letter or someone writing a personal statement. All the substitutes so far, though i am sure there is a better way that has eluded me thus far, lack the punch and sense of the original phrase.